# How can i make all of these commands run together

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, batch-file

I need to make these commands run all together. So i am going to make them run as a batch file then call each line individually to make a pop up message appear on the screen.

But I have tried different methods of trying to get them to run as one single line but cant seem to get it working - any help would be appreciated

Powershell

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("We are proceeding with next step." , "Status")
```

would be great if you guys could help

Comment: Sorry the code didnt post fully 

powershell^
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")^
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("We are proceeding with next step." , "Status")

Comment: Looks just like the same question over here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25836547/powershell-run-message-box-from-cmd

Comment: "Run all together" means what?

Answer (score 0):

In dos, the ampersand & sign can be used to run multiple commands, in sequence. For example:

```
cd C:\ & echo foo
```

Although if you're just running powershell commands why write them to a batch file? Just write a powershell script and run it from command prompt.

See this post: [How to run a PowerShell script from a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335004/how-to-run-a-powershell-script-from-a-batch-file)

Answer (score 0):

If you separate your PS commands by a semi-colon you can run multiple commands from a one-liner from the shell.

E.g.

```
echo "foo"; echo "bar"
```